# Why does my CSS class not affect my HTML page?

Tags: html

I am trying to write this html code but the CSS attributes just don't affect my code.

HTML file:

```css
.hello{
  background color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hi.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hello">
      <p> hi </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your issue is caused by a typo: `background color: #333;` is invalid CSS. The attribute is called `background-color: #333;`. As your issue is caused by a typo, I flag it for closure.

Answer (score 3):

`background color` is not valid. It should be `background-color`

```css
.hello{
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hi.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="hello">
      <p> hi </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `-` between `background` and `color`. You are providing different CSS attributes instead of one.

Do this:

```
.hello {
   background-color: #333; // Add an hyphin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.hello {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Though this is the answer it is a copy of previous answers and does not add any value.

Comment: @Jan That was tough one, that`s why It took me a lot of time to think about it:), after I posted my answer, I saw it had been answered